# How can I externalize or use schema name at runtime while using DB2 queries from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, jdbctemplate

I have developed spring-boot microservice and for Database interaction I am using jdbcTemplate. Currently I am placing all my queries in application.properties as below:
sql.select.query=update SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME set COL_NAME='ABC' where COL2_NAME='XYZ'
and in Dao Layer, Iam using this variable for query.

@Value{sql.select.query}
private query;

The above piece of code is fine and running as expected but now the requirement came up that Schema name should be segregated from query so that in future it can be changed.

Comment: sql.select.query=update **${schema.name}**.TABLE_NAME

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov: But in properties file, does it able to identify ${schema.name}. Since the query is in appl.properties

Comment: Yep. You can set schema.name as another property or pass it through the command line. See this:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thnx much but I was wondering if there is any way that I can pass schema.name similarly as I pass dataSource.username and dataSource.password and it can be picked up at runtime.

Comment: How are you passing dataSource.username and dataSource.password?